# Has anyone succeeded in using Google App Engine with Python version 2.6?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Since Python 2.6 is backward compatible to 2.52 , did anyone succeeded in using it with Google app Engine ( which  supports 2.52 officially ).

I know i should try it myself. But i am a python and web-apps new bee and for me installation and configuration is the hardest part while getting started with something new in this domain.
( .... I am trying it myself in the meanwhile ....)

Thanks

Comment: Update: support for Python version 2.7 has been added to the [App Engine Roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html), so it's on the way!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose logging module crashes if you try to start the dev environment. See [the issue and a workaround](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1159#c7).

After doing that change my code worked in 2.6 without any problems. I suggest using 2.5.x though so there are no other incompatibilities introduced in your code which would make your app fail on the live server.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few issues with using Python 2.6 with the SDK, mostly related to the SDK's sandboxing, which is designed to imitate the sandbox limitations in production. Note, of course, that even if you get Python 2.6 running with the SDK, your code will still have to run under 2.5 in production.