# AppEngine dev_appserver.py aborts with no error message

Tags: python, django, macos, google-app-engine

I have an app which works well live on AppEngine.
However, when I try to run it locally with the dev_appserver.py, it aborts within ~1 second with:

```
    ~/ dev_appserver.py --debug_imports myapp
/opt/local/share/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_file_stub.py:40: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import md5
/opt/local/share/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py:31: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
  import sha
```

I'm on OS X 10.6.3, Python 2.6.4 + Django 1.1.1 + appengine 1.3.1 (all installed via macports)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's aborting?  Those are just warning messages; it it was crashing completely you should be getting a stack trace and an actual error message.

Comment: Yes. It may be gracefully exiting, but it's for sure not remaining running in any way similar to the Django dev server, nor do I see any Python process running which rules out a daemon mode (which I'd doubt anyway was the case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, it seems that after I installed py26-googleappengine using macports and adding its subdirs to my PATH the first dev_appserver.py found was at

> /opt/local/share/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py

When I changed it to be the other copy found at

```
/opt/local/share/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
```

all started working normally.

The two files are vastly different...

Unlike what Adam said, it works fine for me with Python 2.6.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: the answer below is potentially no longer relevant depending on individual use-case as Python 2.7 is now supported on App Engine.

---

App Engine only works with Python 2.5.x

Install 2.5, and run explicitly.
For example:

`python2.5 /path/to/dev_appserver.py myapp`

Comment: related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254028/has-anyone-succeeded-in-using-google-app-engine-with-python-version-2-6

Comment: I switched it over to python2.5 -- still the same result of exiting immediately with not even a warning message now.

Comment: I just started a bounty for this since I still can't get it to work, and with no sign or hint of what could be wrong.

Comment: @Gj:  it might help to update the question to include the command you're now using (with 2.5), and any traceback you get.